# Using the uniq command without sort (sorting)

Tags: batch-file

I am actually writing a batch script and I need to remove duplicate lines using either batch code (which was lame) , uniq, sort, sed, etc. but it CAN NOT SORT the list in the process. Any ideas ?

```
    sort <file> | uniq
```

works great but it sorts my already sorted file.  Any ides ?

```
    cat <file> | uniq
```

fails.

Comment: Seems duplicate of [How to get only the unique results without having to sort data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11939/209677)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is already sorted, you can use uniq command as you gave the example of, i.e.,

## cat  | uniq

sort is not a *requirement* for uniq, it is highly advised because it only eliminates successive duplicates. if a line repeats on line numbers 2,3,4,8, without sort command in the pipe, lines 2 and 8 will be in the output. With sort only line 2 will be on the output.

Hope this is what you are asking

Comment: Why do you say it won't work ? You said file is already "sorted" so, you don't need another sort command. whjne you run the command "cat file|uniq" what in the output tells you it didn't work ? If you are seeing multiples of one or more lines, it means your file was not as *already sorted* as you might think.Any other failure ?? You need to provide an example

Answer (score 2):

The Windows/DOS Batch file below do what you need (I hope...)

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=⌂ delims=" %%a in (thefile.txt) do (
   if not defined line["%%a"] (
      set line["%%a"]=defined
      echo %%a
   )
)
```

Note that the character in `eol=⌂` part must be any char. that does NOT exist in the file; I suggest you to use Ascii-127 (like in my code) or Ascii-255 (that looks like a space).

Please, test the program and report the result.

Antonio

Comment: I copied yours exactly into my code and I'm getting ... "îé delims=" was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @MikeQ: This is strange, the code works on my Win-XP computer with no problem... Anyway, blame the character placed after `eol=` for the error. You may change it by any other char. that does NOT appear in the file, or completely remove the `eol=X ` option if no line in the file start with semicolon. Please report the result...

Answer (score 1):

If you can use e.g. not too ancient version of `bash` (that supports array variables), you can easily do it in a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a LINES
while read; do
    for n in "${LINES[@]}"; do
        if [[ $n == $REPLY ]]; then
            continue 2
        fi
    done
    LINES=("${LINES[@]}" "$REPLY")
    echo "$REPLY"
done
```

If your files are big, awk or Perl will be probably better.